# Cannot build with jar command - java.io.IOException: line too long

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, runnable-jar

I have folder that looks like so:

```
foo/
 Bar.java
 Bar.class
 Foo.java
 Foo.class
 manifest.mf
```

the .java files are both in a package called x:

```
package x;
```

I generate the .class files with:

```
javac foo/*.java
```

then I try to package to runnable jar format with:

```
jar cmf foo.jar foo/manifest.mf foo/*.class
```

but I get this error:

```
 java.io.IOException: line too long
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:381)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:228)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:80)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:72)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:264)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1669)
```

The manifest.mf contents are just:

```
Main-Class: x.Bar
```

It compiles with `javac` so not sure what's going on, or why it doesn't like the manifest file, anyone know?

Comment: if you have `package x;` in your java files they have to be inside folder with name `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper command line will be

```
jar -c -m foo/manifest.mf -f foo.jar foo/*.class
```

Comment: that worked, wow that was harder than expected to figure out, thanks

Comment: In your command `jar` thinks that ` foo.jar` is manifest. Try to parse it and fails.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that for "jar cmf" command first argument should be path to manifest.
As described in documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html

Could you try in your case build it with next command ?

```
jar cmf foo/manifest.mf foo.jar foo/*.class
```